# How to avoid mouse click using javascript

Tags: javascript, html

For doing a tabs i have taken reference from w3css tabs there they given three tabs which are like london, paris, tokyo like that on refresh of the page all div contents will hidden when click on any tab the respective content is going to open.
    In my project i should have tabs like that only

```
                 |   tab1          tab2           tab3
                 |
link for tab page|
                 |
                 |
```

this is the design i had in my project when i click on link for the tab page the tab1 tab2 tab3 are appeared that time the contents of all tabs are hidden thats right but after opened tab1 i do some selection in form expect data from database that time page going to refresh so all the tabs going to hidden stage

i am looking for like this when i click link for the tab page all the tabs should be hidden when i click on any tab it should not go to hidden stage until either other tabs should click or link for the tab page

**code**

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<title>W3.CSS</title>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://www.w3schools.com/lib/w3.css">
<style>
.city {display:none;}
</style>
<body>

<div class="w3-container">
 <a href="tabs.html">links for the tab page</a>

  <div class="w3-row">
    <a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="openCity(event, 'London');">
      <div class="w3-third tablink w3-bottombar w3-hover-light-grey w3-padding">Tab1</div>
    </a>
    <a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="openCity(event, 'Paris');">
      <div class="w3-third tablink w3-bottombar w3-hover-light-grey w3-padding">Tab2</div>
    </a>
    <a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="openCity(event, 'Tokyo');">
      <div class="w3-third tablink w3-bottombar w3-hover-light-grey w3-padding">Tab3</div>
    </a>
  </div>

  <div id="London" class="w3-container city">
    <h2>London</h2>
    <p>London is the capital city of England.</p>
  </div>

  <div id="Paris" class="w3-container city">
    <h2>Paris</h2>
    <p>Paris is the capital of France.</p>
  </div>

  <div id="Tokyo" class="w3-container city">
    <h2>Tokyo</h2>
    <p>Tokyo is the capital of Japan.</p>
  </div>
</div>

<script>
function openCity(evt, cityName) {
  var i, x, tablinks;
  x = document.getElementsByClassName("city");
  for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
     x[i].style.display = "none";
  }
  tablinks = document.getElementsByClassName("tablink");
  for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
     tablinks[i].className = tablinks[i].className.replace(" w3-border-red", "");
  }
  document.getElementById(cityName).style.display = "block";
  evt.currentTarget.firstElementChild.className += " w3-border-red";
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: your question is not clear

Comment: Not least because the title seems to have nothing to do with the text.

Comment: @user2181397 see i  have changed question description

Comment: Your title asks `how to get w3 border color with JavaScript`, but in the text you ask how you can handle different clicks on different pages. What are you actually asking about?

Answer (score 0):

If you have only London related information in Page2, you can directly set div with id London as visible.

However, you can also try having the city related information in page1 and just call the openCity method on page1 itself.

Here is the link : [JS bin Working Example](http://jsbin.com/vukaqofiqo/edit?html,js,output)

Comment: How to set direct visibility for london in page2

Comment: i have this example in w3 schools

Comment: you could add an class "active" and have css .active{ display : block;}

Comment: <div id="London" class="w3-container city active">
  <h2>London</h2>
  <p>London is the capital city of England.</p>
</div>  am not getting w3-border-red

Comment: for  w3-border-red border color something need to do

Answer (score 0):

**Page2** .
Try this and remove `</script>` from line 21 in Page1

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://www.w3schools.com/lib/w3.css">
    <body class="w3-container">
    <h2>Tabs in a Grid</h2>
    <div class="w3-row">
      <a href="#" onclick="openCity(event, 'London');" id="myId">
        <div class="w3-third tablink w3-bottombar w3-hover-light-grey w3-padding">London</div>
      </a> 
    </div>
    <div id="London" class="w3-container city">
      <h2>London</h2>
      <p>London is the capital city of England.</p>
    </div>
    <script>
    function openCity(evt, cityName) {
      var i, x, tablinks;
      x = document.getElementsByClassName("city");
      for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
         x[i].style.display = "none";
      }
      tablinks = document.getElementsByClassName("tablink");
      for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
         tablinks[i].className = tablinks[i].className.replace(" w3-border-red", "");
      }
      document.getElementById(cityName).style.display = "block";
      evt.currentTarget.firstElementChild.className += " w3-border-red";
    }
       document.onreadystatechange = function(){
         if(document.readyState === 'complete'){
         document.getElementById("myId").click();
         }
         }
    </script>
    </body>
   </html>
```

Comment: absolutely perfect

Comment: ya.. but  you written new lines it may work if you do some change in existing javascript only